# migrating from NET Core 2.1 to NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

i have a NET Core2.1 console application and it works all god, but after migrating to NET Core 3.1
after 1-2 hours of running the app there is a message

**Queue is full. Waiting... (hint: increase queue size by configuring "net-queue-size-multiplier: 1-30)**

```
Queue is full. Waiting... (hint: increase queue size by configuring "net-queue-size-multiplier: 1-30)
Detected thread scheduler timeout: request ID: 0; pending count: 4
Detected thread scheduler timeout: request ID: 0; pending count: 4
Detected thread scheduler timeout: request ID: 0; pending count: 4
Detected thread scheduler timeout: request ID: 0; pending count: 4
```

and app stop responding.. how to solve this ?

[here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgGWp.png)

Comment: Are yo urunning with latest version of Core 3.1? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true

Comment: No, i use 3.1.0,but  i will try now with the latest version.

Comment: Same problem with the latest version.

Comment: Do you have more than 4 in the queue?  Looks like the queue size is 4 and may of been larger in 2.1.